# Opening 2 top level windows (quickly/pygtk)

Tags: python, application-development, gtk, quickly, pygtk

Is there a way using quickly to have an appliaction have two completly seperate windows (not a window with a dialog) And be able to open each of the windows from each other and maybe even also from the command line: eg, application_name --window_title

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you'll have to create a different Window to do this, the default main window that Quickly creates is meant to run only one at a time.

Comment: I think I have got it, but what i'm trying to figure out now is how to use command line arguments with quickly. What i have done is I have got an if_else statement to check if there is a command line argument and if it is the command `"--browse"` and if it is it should set the window to open as the browse window. Otherwise it should open the main window. The problem is that the prebuilt code already does stuff and it gives me this error on run: `error: no such option: --browse` Any help would be good!

Comment: If you need source file look here http://ubuntuone.com/0IjxnyNzKr4UypMFEojrGi